# Add Node.js module to Cordova App

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, npm, windows-10-mobile

I would like to add [Discord.io](https://github.com/izy521/discord.io) to my cordova (Windows 10 mobile) app.

I've executed `npm install discord.io` in the cordova project direcotry.
It creates the `node_modules` directory and also adds discord.io to the NPM-Dependencies:

[image: Project-Explorer]

If I try to initialize the discord.io lib like the example from GitHub:

```
var DiscordClient = require('discord.io');
var bot = new DiscordClient({
    autorun: true,
    email: "my@email.com",
    password: "secret_passw0rd"
});

bot.on('ready', function() {
    console.log(bot.username + " - (" + bot.id + ")");
});

bot.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, rawEvent) {
    if (message === "ping") {
        bot.sendMessage({
            to: channelID,
            message: "pong"
        });
    }
});
```

I get the error message:

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'require' is undefined
```

I also tried to use `cordova.require('discord.io');`, results in this error:

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: module discord.io not found
```

How am I going to correctly include and initialize this lib?

Comment: You probably can't. It is designed to run under Node.JS not in a web browser.

Comment: Okay thanks @Quentin , any chance to get Discord.io working with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) on cordova?

Comment: So is it works with browserify ?

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?